# Add measures or calculated columns to a matrix widget in a PowerBI report:

Tags: powerbi, dax

I tried to add measures as a new column in a PowerBI matrix widget, but matrix widget does not seem to be able to receive measures as new columns.

Here is what I have and tried:

I have a table structure:

```
"data" table
---------------
"Attribute" column
"Value" column
```

In the report I have a matrix widget:

- on rows: I have the attributes,
- on columns: I have the values

The numbers are counts of the specific value given in the matrix columns

display result is like this:

```
                OK  State1  State2  
"Firmware"      70    12      18    
"Obsolescence"  75    08      17    
"Signature"     65    21      14
```

But I need to add extra calculated columns or find an other way like:

- "State3" which could be calculated "State3" = ("OK" - "State1")

expected display result is like this:

```
                OK  State1  State2 State3
"Firmware"      70    12      18     58
"Obsolescence"  75    08      17     67
"Signature"     65    21      14     44
```

So I tried by inserting a measure in the matrix column
but this does not works like this.

Is it even possible to do something like this with a matrix?
I cannot add measure as a new column in the matrix, this does not work in the matrix widget.

Comment: Use this as measure: State3= SUMX(YourTableName, [OK] - [State1])

Comment: This is a matrix not a table, so "OK" and "State1" and "State2" are  values in the table not a column title. "data" is the table with columns: "Value", "Attribute".

Comment: Then where do those values (70, 12 etc.) come from ? Quantity column also exists?

Comment: values are the count of the number of values found in the "data" table. No other columns can help for this yet. Check the table structure : only available columns are "Value" and "Attribute".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. then you need to change chart type from matrix to table, then create this measures, then add to your table:

```
OK = 
CALCULATE(COUNT(YourTbl[Value]), YourTbl[Value] = "OK")

State1 = 
CALCULATE(COUNT(YourTbl[Value]), YourTbl[Value] = "State1")

State3 = [OK] - [State1]
```

If we put it on a table visual :

[image: Gremlin]

Comment: Here the result is "State3" is a subcolumn of "OK" / "State1" / "State2" columns
I need the 'State3' column as a top level column. Is it possible ?

Comment: Not sub columns. sub measure.because you defined it as such: It consist of subsets of whole table due to filter condition : (YourTable[Value] = "OK"). It has the same level of hierarchy on the matrix.

Comment: This does not match my expected result. I added an expected display result example to be more clear. "State3" column should be "on the same level" / same kind as other columns.

Comment: OK. then check my above answer. I updated it!

Comment: Ok thanks, seems the only way to do it . I have have more complicated stuff to handle also, but I will post a new question if needed.

Comment: Hi @Malo. Nice to hear that your problem is solved. If you demand more help from me, Then you can update the post and add your question. I will try to help as much as I can!